# Testing Kotlin Coroutines (Flow vs Publisher)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a reasonably simple bit of code - every second ping some handler with the current timestamp:

```kotlin
private val clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone()

private fun now() = clock.instant()

suspend fun ping(pinger: suspend (Instant) -> Unit) {  
    repeat(5) {
        pinger(now())  
        if (it < 4) {  
            delay(1.seconds)  
        }  
    }
}
```

Which I want to expose as a reactive Producer:

```kotlin
fun publishPing() = publish { ping(::send) }
```

In practice, it works - but when testing:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun `test publishPing`() = runTest {

    var count = 0

    publishPing().collect {
        count++
        assertTrue { EPOCH.isBefore(it) }
        assertTrue { it.isBefore(now()) }
    }

    assertEquals(5, count) // Pass
    assertEquals(4000, currentTime) // AssertionFailedError: Expected:4000; Actual:0
}
```

The virtual time doesn't get incremented, and he test takes 4+ seconds to run (eg the calls to `delay()` aren't being handled by the test dispatcher).

Doing the same with a flow all works as expected (and runs in milliseconds).

```kotlin
fun flowPing() = flow { ping(::emit) }

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun `test flowPing`() = runTest {

    var count = 0

    flowPing().collect {
        count++
        assertTrue { EPOCH.isBefore(it) }
        assertTrue { it.isBefore(now()) }
    }

    assertEquals(5, count) // Pass
    assertEquals(4000, currentTime) // Pass
}
```

I have a vague idea of what is [not] going on (the coroutines-test support isn't Hooked into the coroutines/reactive support?) - but what do I need to do to sort it?

FWIW the same behaviour happens with coroutines 1.5.x and runBlockingTest (code above from coroutines 1.6 and runTest)